# ASP.NET How to remove double quotation from parameterized SQL query?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0, parameterized-query

I seems not working because double quotations are also inserted when i use parameterized SQL query. How can i remove the double quotations?

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SORT", (rdbAscending.Checked) ? "ASC" :
>   "DESC");

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626363/mysql-conditional-order-by-asc-desc-for-date-column) to see how you can use parameters in the ORDER BY clause.