# Order by with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like use `CASE` statement in `ORDER BY` clausule like this:

```
ORDER BY  
    CASE
        WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 0 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` ASC
        WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 1 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` DESC
    END
```

But I can use `ASC`/`DESC` keywords only after the `END`.

There is some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like:

```
SELECT columns FROM tables WHERE condition 
ORDER BY  
CASE    
  WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 0 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` ASC,
  WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 1 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` DESC
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following link for reference, I've put this together for your scenario.

[MySQL conditional ORDER BY ASC/DESC for date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626363/mysql-conditional-order-by-asc-desc-for-date-column)

```
ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 0 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` END ASC,
      CASE WHEN `Delivery`.`type` = 1 THEN `Delivery`.`quantity` END DESC;
```